# How to fix airodump-ng continuously changing channels on Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bash, kali-linux

I am running a Wifi adapter with the chipset AR8812AU on Kali Linux 2019.1. I am trying to run airmon-ng, targeted o a specific AP using command:

```
 airmon-ng --bssid $APmac -c $APchannel wlan0
```

The problem is the interface is displaying the message:

```
fixed channel wlan: $channel
```

and the channel keeps changing every second or so.

This makes me unable to run commands because the AP I am trying to associate with has a fixed channel, and the message i get is:

```
13:58:53  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 70:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) on channel $channel

13:58:57  wlan0 is on channel $channel, but the AP uses channel 1
```

with $channel always being the one that changes every second.

I have tried giving a fixed channel to wlan0 with the interface being either up or down

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 channel 1
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

The commands were successful, however the issue still appears.

Comment: What the... Why are you using "$APchannel"? This is abnormal.

Comment: Do you perhaps have software active that is scanning for and connecting to Wi-Fi networks? Like `wpa_supplicant` or `systemd-networkd`.